# What causes “pam_unix … conversation failed” in auth.log

Tags: sudo, authentication, pam

There are thousands of entries in my `auth.log` like this:

```
sudo: pam_unix(sudo:auth): conversation failed
```

What causes these to occur? I'd like to fix whatever it is but I'm a bit mystified as to where to look. `visudo` looks ok to me but I'm no expert at it's syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this appear when someone presses <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> at `sudo` password prompt.